# Set custom default CommandTimeout for all new Command Objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlcommand, sqlclient, command-timeout

The default [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) value is 30 seconds.  You can manually change the value on an instance of the command object by doing the following

```vb
Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
cmd.CommandTimeout = 60
```

Is there a way to specify a different default value, such that all new command objects will automatically have this value within your solution when they are created?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1001713/1178314) (Not flagging as dup, there is some significant differences in those questions imo, even if answers to both are same.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know no, there is no way to change this default. The constructor code for a SqlCommand is this:

```
public SqlCommand()
{
    this.ObjectID = Interlocked.Increment(ref _objectTypeCount);
    this._commandTimeout = 30;
    this._updatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.Both;
    this._prepareHandle = -1;
    this._rowsAffected = -1;
    this._notificationAutoEnlist = true;
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

A possible workaround is to use a predefined SqlCommand passed as argument to the constructor that takes a SqlCommand as argument.

So you could create a global SqlCommand (a template)

```
 Dim commandTemplate60 = new SqlCommand()
 commandTemplate60.Timeout = 60
```

and then when you need a command with a timeout of 60 seconds

```
Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(commandTemplate60)
```

However, setting directly the Timeout, doesn't seems to be a lot of work

Comment: Not constant value for default value `._commandTimeout = 30;` ?